# rolling a dice with javascript and checking win or lose

Tags: javascript

i have one javascript code that roll a dice with random number from 0 to 9999, now the script start rolling the dice when i press the button, but its rolling and rolling without stopping. Can you help me to make this code to pick one number after this rolling and to check is it lose or it is win depends of the type of the game (which is in the first lanes) and to give this status forward to the javascript so it can show the number that the code pick and show win or lose. Here is the code:

```
    var playing = 0;
    $('#play').on('click', function (){
        if (playing == 0){
            playing = 1;
            $(this).html('...ROLLING...');
            $('.error_cont').css('visibility','hidden');
            var amount = parseInt($('#bet_value').val());
            $('#bet_value').val($('#bet_value').val().replace(/\D/g,''));
            var error = '';


            if (error == ''){
                $('.bet_result').text('ROLLING');
                $('.bet_cont_roll_inside').removeClass('lose_bet_inside win_bet_inside');
                $('.bet_result').removeClass('result_lose result_win');
                $('.rolling_bet').removeClass('result_lose result_win');
                $('.rolling_bet').removeClass('flash shake');

                var loop = setInterval(function(){
                    $('.rolling_bet').html(getRandomInt(0, 9999));
                }, 100);
                var loop2 = setInterval(function(){
                    var randint =  getRandomInt(1, 7);

                    $('.bet_cont_roll_inside').css('background-image','url(http://localhost/image/dice/dice'+ randint +'.png)');
                }, 300);
                $.post( "http://localhost/index.php", {'amount': amount, 'type': type, '_token': _token}, function( data ){
                    if (data.success){
                        setTimeout(function (){
                            clearInterval(loop);
                            clearInterval(loop2);
                            var result = data.rolled;
                            var status = data.win ? 'WIN' : 'LOSE';
                            if(status=='WIN') {
                                $('.bet_cont_roll_inside').addClass('win_bet_inside');
                                $('.bet_result').addClass('result_win');
                                $('.rolling_bet').addClass('flash result_win');
                                if (data.profit === undefined || data.profit === null) {
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').prepend('<div class="his_won home_bet_his animated flipInX"><div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> YOU WON</div> +0 coins</div>');
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').find('.home_bet_his:last').remove()
                                } else {    
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').prepend('<div class="his_won home_bet_his animated flipInX"><div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> YOU WON</div> +'+ (data.profit + amount)+' coins</div>');
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').find('.home_bet_his:last').remove()
                                }


                            } else {
                                $('.bet_cont_roll_inside').addClass('lose_bet_inside');
                                $('.bet_result').addClass('result_lose');
                                $('.rolling_bet').addClass('shake result_lose');
                                if (data.profit === undefined || data.profit === null) {
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').prepend('<div class="his_lost home_bet_his animated flipInX"><div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> YOU LOST</div> -0 coins</div>');
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').find('.home_bet_his:last').remove()

                                } else {
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').prepend('<div class="his_lost home_bet_his animated flipInX"><div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> YOU LOST</div> -'+amount+' coins</div>');
                                    $('.his_latest_rolls').find('.home_bet_his:last').remove()
                                }
                            }

                            if (data.total_bets > 0){
                                $('#balance').html(data.coins);
                                $('#total_bets').html(data.total_bets);
                                $('#my_bets').html(data.my_bets);
                            }

                            $('.bet_result').text(status);
                            $('.rolling_bet').text(result);
                            setTimeout(function (){
                                playing = 0;
                                $('#play').html('ROLL THE DICE');
                            }, 200);
                        }, 800);
                    } else {
                        clearInterval(loop);
                        clearInterval(loop2);
                        $('#bet_value').val('');
                        var update_noty = noty({
                                    theme: 'csgonoty',
                                    text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>' + data.error,
                                    layout: 'topCenter',
                                    type: 'error',
                                    animation: {
                                        open: 'animated flipInX', // Animate.css class names
                                        close: 'animated flipOutX', // Animate.css class names
                                        easing: 'swing',
                                        speed: 50 // opening & closing animation speed
                                    }
                                }); 
                    }
                }, 'json');
            } else {
                $('.error_cont').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> ' + error);
                $('.error_cont').css('visibility','visible');
                $('#bet_value').val('');
            }
        }

    });




function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Do you expect we debug your code by just looking at it ?

Comment: Omg ! This much of code :P

Comment: I told you its rolling the dice and it wont stop and didn't pick number just rolling, what should i give you more?

Comment: @tyrlaka: Not *more*, but *less*. Can you please create a [MCVE example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem? You can’t expect us to search the needle in that haystack of code.

Comment: I edit my post and this is the code that is rolling the dice, the code working until this lane:
`$.post( "http://localhost/index.php", {'amount': amount, 'type': type, '_token': _token}, function( data ){
`
Before this lane it's should start rolling and pick a number, after this lane it's shoud check is it win or its lose and show the picked number with the class win or lose, but it's not stop rolling

Comment: What does the dev console debugger tell you?

Comment: it show absolutely nothing.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your $.post request was actually delivered with success?
If the request failed then your intervals will never be cleared.

Try following:

```
$.post( "http://localhost/index.php", {'amount': amount, 'type': type, '_token': _token}, function( data ) {
    // your old $.post processing code here
}, 'json').fail(function () {
    clearInterval(loop);
    clearInterval(loop2);
});
```

UPDATE: additional explanation

Assume that your request failed. In this case the .fail(function) will be called and dice will stop rolling.
Your code for WIN/LOSS clearly depends on successful request so you should make sure that the request will succeed.
I assume that the server is under your control, so you may check what is going on.

Also now you may try to handle the POST request failure like this:

```
$.post( "http://localhost/index.php", {'amount': amount, 'type': type, '_token': _token}, function( data ) {
    // your old $.post processing code here
}, 'json').fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    clearInterval(loop);
    clearInterval(loop2);
    // call some function to show the message
    //showErrorMessage('Oh no!');    
    // or just show alert dialog with the message
    alert('The request failed ' + jqXHR.statusCode() + ' ' + textStatus);
    // or push the request result into the browser console
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

It is also advisable to use build-in debugger in web browser.
For instance Firefox has [nice one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger) and Chrome [too](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Comment: I am not sure that the request is successful, i don't know how to test it, cuz i don't really know javascript, i try with your code, but its the same only that the numbers in the dice are not spinning...

Comment: Thank you about it, it give me fail the error is:
"parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token
I have one variable "token" which is like this:
`var _token = 'km1qunP1x0Z8HbCUQDZ0jUzhGnDYzDv2W3uw5RW0';`
maybe here is the problem? I don't know what this token mean...
If i remove this token, the dice roll the numbers but its rolling and rolling.... (like before with no stop...)

Comment: **"parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token** - This means that the json delivered by the server is not valid. You may try to validate your json with [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/), it will also show where the error is. Or add the json to your post.

Comment: It gives me error here:
`$.post("http://localhost/",
{
    "amount": amount,
    "type": type,
    "_token": _token
},
function(data){`
on the 1st line:
Parse error on line 1:
$.post("http: // local
^
Expecting '{', '['

Comment: I try to remove JSON after this script, but its fail it give me error "Undefined"... How can i make this post request to work with json or maybe with other method??

Comment: I'm speaking about the JSON delivered with the response **FROM** the server. The `{ "amount": amount, "type": type, "_token": _token }` is an javascript object which you are passing **TO** the `$.post()` request function and it is not so important right now. Is the server under your control?

Comment: At the moment i make it in localhost, but i don't want to make any changes when i upload it to a web hosting... i don't understand javascript so much so can u help me to make this post request to work....

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm not able to help you any more. Assuming that the problem is the invalid JSON delivered from the server I may only suggest to you to fix it on the SERVER SIDE. With valid JSON delivered to the browser JSON parser will then stop complaining and the ajax response will not fail therefore showing what you wish to be displayed.

Comment: Okey, do you know how to fix it from the server side?